# How Would I Make A Random Seed/Hash To Make Rand Actually Random?

Tags: c++, random

how would i generate a seed or hash that would make rand actually random? I need it to change every time it picks a number. New to c++ so i'm not exactly sure how to do this. Thanks! :D

Comment: @DevanshMohanKaushik -- The referenced question/answers in your suggested duplicate is a bad suggestion, as they advocate use of time as a seed -- which is bad practice and can lead to duplicate random numbers between processes that seed at the same time (think web servers)

Comment: @soren it also contains the links to the other useful answers including the one you mentioned in the coment section.

Comment: This question is for C++ while the duplicate marked is asking for C.

Answer (score 5):

With C++11 you can use `std::random_device`. I would suggest you to watch [link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) for a comprehensive guide.

Extracting the **essential** message from the **video link** :  You should *never* use `srand` & `rand`, but instead use `std::random_device` and `std::mt19937` -- for most cases, the following would be what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,99);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        std::cout << dist(mt) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an "actually random" random number generator without sampling environmental data or accessing a quantum random number source. Consider accessing the ANU random number source if you require truly random numbers (http://qrng.anu.edu.au/FAQ.php#api).

Otherwise, Boost provides a more robust pseudo-RNG, which should suffice for most purposes: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_random.html

Comment: Note that much of boost random was standardized with c++11, and can be accessed through `<random>`.